# EXP template inside another EXP template dosent work

Tags: channel, query, fields

I have install a plugin to get channels. And that was i have used in template

```
{exp:getchannels}
{channel_name}
{/exp:getchannels}
```

From this I got the result i.e. list of channels. thats ok. working good.
and then I need to execute a query like this

```
{exp:query sql="Select CONCAT('field_id_',field_id) 'field_id', field_name, BASE64_DECODE(field_settings) 'field_settings', field_label
     from exp_channel_fields f join exp_channels c on c.field_group = f.group_id where c.channel_name = 'programme' order by field_order"}
     <br/>{field_name}<br/>
{/exp:query}
```

from this I got the result of particular channel that is "Programme"

Now my query is that, I would like to use that `query EXP` inside the `getchannel EXP`, like below mentioned

```
{exp:getchannels}
{channel_name}
{exp:query sql="Select CONCAT('field_id_',field_id) 'field_id', field_name, BASE64_DECODE(field_settings) 'field_settings', field_label
     from exp_channel_fields f join exp_channels c on c.field_group = f.group_id where c.channel_name = '{channel_name}' order by field_order"}
     <br/>{field_name}<br/>
{/exp:query}
{/exp:getchannels}
```

Now problem is that, that `query EXP` returns blank when i execute that inside `getchannel EXP`.
Here I would like to get the fields of each channel what channels are getting by `getchannel EXP`, yes same like `FOREACH LOOP`.

If i `echo` this query and `execute` that inside `PHPMYADMIN` it returns result exactly what i want.

I think there is something wrong with that. Don't getting the idea whats wrong in that.
Can Anybody help me to solve that.?
I stuck at this point.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you cant use php inside the query tag sql. If you dont believe me, look at the source code for query module. From memory its in system/module/query. Remove this:

`BASE64_DECODE(field_settings) 'field_settings', field_label`

Now this works:

`{exp:query sql="Select CONCAT('field_id_',field_id) 'field_id', field_name, c.channel_name {!--BASE64_DECODE(field_settings) 'field_settings', field_label--}
     from exp_channel_fields f join exp_channels c on c.field_group = f.group_id order by c.channel_name asc, f.field_order asc"}
     {channel_name}
{field_id}, {field_name}

{/exp:query}`

But i see you want to group by channel name, so wrap it with your {exp:getchannels} tag like you did in your example (sorry, using my ipad...takes too long to show code). That should work.

Update:  If exp:getchannels is a plugin it wont work. Modules get parsed before plugins [parse order](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf). So to change to

`{exp:getchannels parse="inward"}`

However, you still need to decode the field settings, so your best solution is to create a plugin to run the query, then loop through the output and decode the field settings row.

You can also run queries [here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/tools/data/sql_query_form.html). And check db [here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/tools/data/sql_manage_tables.html)

Comment: Hey dadonbike, thanks sir.. somehow this being helpful to me..

Comment: No problems. Also, if this question is resolved please mark it as answered so others can benefit from your question